# New Extra Commands and It is never declared?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

my problem is in this Java-Me Application  : http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Making_a_phone_call_programmatically_using_platformRequest()_in_Java_ME

this application lets the user dial a number inserted into a text field.

Now all are ok and no errors and it can be installed on my nokia n8 fine, But the problem is : there are two extra commands "Call" And "Add From Contacts" in the commands menu in the application ! how it comes to the commands ??? there are no any commands declared have those names !!!!

The declared commands are : "Call" (this another one) and "Exit" only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When make a new text field and set its text input to PHONENUMBER , then the system automatically generate a new commands "CAll" And "Add From Contacts" to help user to select a phone number or dial it ! hhh but that was not fine for me so i replaced PHONENUMBER with NUMERIC and now its ok :) Thank you